# Why in Android Studio I obtain this "@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode" error when I add any new view style setting?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, ide

I am absolutly new in Android development and I am doing my first experiments using **Android Studio** as IDE and I have the following proboem.

I have this **activity_main.xml** file that contain the layout settings for my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Happy Birthday Ben!" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="From Pippo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/androidparty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Into the preview view I have selected the **API 15: Android 4.0.3** (clicking on the litle android green robot button).

I obtain my view rendered into the preview but every time that I add some setting it give me the following error message:

```
Rendering Problems
@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode
(2 similar errors not shown)
```

But I can't find where are shown these **2 similar errors**. I think that, in Android Studio, have to exist something like the Eclipse **Problems view** but I can't find it.

So what this error means? Why is it shown ? (also if my application is correctly performed) and where can I find the equivalent section of the the Eclipse **Problems view** in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I guess because of this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163572. Just choose newer API's in the preview mode, and test API 15 in a real device or emulator.